# How to include filter link in the summary - badge list plug-in

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I've created summary which gives me Open, close and pending statues and provided the link to the page 4 which has detailed report.

Now I need to provide filter based on the selection in the report. Example - if 'Open' selected in summary, filter should apply for 'open' in page 4 report.

I'm new to apex, can you please help me with simple and easy way of doing this.

`````
select 'Open' label
, count(*) value
, 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':4:'||:APP_SESSION||':::::' link
from eba_demo_projects 
where status = 'Open'
UNION ALL
select 'Close' label
, count(*) value
, 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':4:'||:APP_SESSION||':::::' link
from eba_demo_proj_milestones
where status = 'Close'
UNION ALL
select 'Pending' label
, count(*) value
, 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':4:'||:APP_SESSION||':::::' link 
from eba_demo_proj_tasks
where status = 'Pending'````
`````

Comment: Where did you source the plugin? What APEX version are you using? It may be a case of substituting &LINK. in a plugin attribute.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create an item (probably hidden item) in page 4, lets say P4_status.
Then in the link column of your sql query, you need to add like this:

```
select 'Open' label
, count(*) value
, 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':4:'||:APP_SESSION||':::RP,4:P4_status:'||status||'' as link
from eba_demo_projects 
where status = 'Open'
UNION ALL
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

1. Create the new item like P4_STATUS
2. Change the item type like select list you can update the select list what are the list you want after that you can save it
3. create one dynamic action for P4_STATUS like change event refresh action
4. refresh the badge list region
5. badge list region below query you can update it
6. and the classic report item to submit column you can select the P4_STATUS column

```
select label, value, link from(
select 'Open' label, count(*) value , 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':4:'||:APP_SESSION||':::::' link from eba_demo_projects  where status = 'Open'
UNION ALL
select 'Close' label , count(*) value, 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':4:'||:APP_SESSION||':::::' link from eba_demo_proj_milestones where status = 'Close'
UNION ALL
select 'Pending' label , count(*) value , 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':4:'||:APP_SESSION||':::::' link  from eba_demo_proj_tasks where status = 'Pending')
where (label = :P4_STATUS or :P4_STATUS is null)
```

7. finally you can save and run the page and check it
   it will work, more doubts pls ask me

once you are ok then update the comments